# Discord.JS Get Attachment URL and send in channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have this bot code "discord.js v13", I need to get the URL of the attached file and send the link right away. how can I do this? I will leave the code part below

```
            // save file in folder 'musicas'
            stream.pipe(createWriteStream(__dirname + `/musicas/${pegaid}.mp3`)).on('finish', () => {

                // Sending the attachment, and its link
                try {
                    message.channel.send({
                        files: [{
                            attachment: (__dirname + `/musicas/${musicid}.mp3`),
                            name: `${musicid}.mp3`
                        }],
                    });
                } catch (e) {
                    return message.channel.send(`${message.author}, Error ao tentar converter a música!`);
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to send the URL of the attached file. Unfortunately, you can only send the URL after sending the attachment itself first.

```js
const image = await message.channel.send({ files: [{ attachment: `full-path`, name: `something.mp3` }] });
return message.channel.send({ content: `${image.attachments.first().proxyURL}` });
```

Read More about it in the discord.js documentation [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageAttachment?scrollTo=proxyURL).

Comment: Thanks bro <333 I tried something similar before, but I didn't use an await

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it worked :D